# Copy/Paste variable dataset between workbooks without clipboard

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to optimize some of my coding and managed to cut and speed it up a lot. However there are some things that are still quite clunky (and me still a noob). Backstory is that my code is opening source and target files, copies a lot of data of variable length, closes source and then does a lot of operations and finally saves target file.

One of the things Id like is to do if possible is a direct copy of data without using clipboard, activating workbooks, selecting sheets (whatever of this is possible to pack into more efficient code that I am currently having)

```
Windows("SOURCE.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Data").Select
Range("A2:AX10").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("TARGET.xlsm").Activate
Range("A2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Is it possible to do a selection (A2:AX10 and all the way down to last row) in SOURCE file-Data sheet and directly copy it to TARGET file-Data sheet cell A2 without using clipboard.

The reason why I use A2:AX10 and then selection down is because I have a lot of blank cells in the whole data set and this way I get entire data.

I would like to be able to to that selection and use it as a range in this line

```
Workbooks(“SOURCE”).Worksheets("Data").Range(“A2:AX10 & ALLTHEWAYDOWN”).Copy _Workbooks(“TARGET”).Worksheets("Data").Range(“A2")
```

I was trying to solve this but I dont end up with desired result. When I try doing selection and setting as range then both trying copy range with activitng workbooks and in the direct copy mode I get 1004 error.

Is it possible to optimize this chunk and make it work. It would improve a lot of my VBA.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
With Workbooks("SOURCE.xlsm").Sheets("Data")
    .Range("A2:AX10", .Range("A2:AX10").End(xlDown)).Copy Workbooks("TARGET.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Range("A2")
End With
```

You could probably also use `CurrentRegion` rather than `End(xlDown`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Rory for a fast and elegant solution. It works well in the test files. Ill try to implement it wherever applicable now.

Answer (score 1):

You can set one range's values (the range where you would want to paste values) equal to a source range's values (the range which you would previously have copied).

```
Sub paste_values()

    Dim wb_A As Workbook, ws_A As Worksheet
    Dim wb_B As Workbook, ws_B As Worksheet
    Dim last_row As Long

    Set wb_A = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws_A = wb_A.Sheets(1)

    Set wb_B = Workbooks("WorkbookB")
    Set ws_B = wb_B.Sheets(1)

    With ws_A
        last_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    ws_B.Range("A2:AX" & last_row).Value = ws_A.Range("A2:AX" & last_row).Value

End Sub
```

This code is setting the new range's values equal to the original range. It prevents the need to activate sheets or workbooks, whilst also copying data to a range without filling the clipboard.

I would also recommend using `last_row = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` to find the last row of your data. Although you do need to ensure you use this on a column which you know contains continuous data.

Comment: Hi Turner, I like this solution as well. Its really clear and elegant. 
It did not work until I changed both references to Workbooks(""). I liked Rory's solution because yours came out with weird format on some columns (dates for example). This is something I did not anticipate before so I havent mentioned it. Sorry about that. Thank you for the great solution.